# Stop my zombie Google Apps Script that checks website status

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

A while back I found http://www.labnol.org/internet/website-uptime-monitor/21060/ with an approach to quickly setting up a Google Docs script to check the status of a simple website I was running. I set it up and all was well. It did a decent job for costing nothing and taking 5 minutes to put in place.

The thing is, I don't need it anymore, that site is no longer live. So to prevent more notifications I deleted the google doc that had been created during that process.

Only, I continued getting emails about the script errors. Despite having moved the script to the trash, the script was somehow still running.

I followed a link from one of the emails to some sort of script management page, and disabled the settings for "Send notifications" (apologies, I didn't take notes and can't get back to that page anymore, so I forget the exact options).

So as it stands, the document is no longer appearing in my google docs/drive search results, and those settings are supposedly turned off. Yet the script is somehow **still running**.

Here's an example of the current email I receive (roughly every 2 minutes):

> Your script, Copy of Website Monitor - Digital Inspiration, has recently failed to finish >successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this >script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.
>
> The script is used by the document Copy of Website Monitor - Digital Inspiration.
>
> Details:

```
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
12/8/14 10:13 PM    secondCheck     Failed to send email: no recipient (line 126, file "labnol")    time-based  12/8/14 10:13 PM
```

> Sincerely,
>
> Google Apps Script

How can I kill it?

Comment: If you make a new empty doc, then go into the script editor, try navigating to "Resources" > "All your triggers". You might see the trigger that's currently calling your script. If so, try to disable it, or at least disable the error notifications.

Comment: There's already a Q&A about this, although [Amit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27393872/1677912) is better. This was an acknowledged bug, and was presumably fixed according to [note 32 on Issue 143](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=143#c32), from @eric-koleda.

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke access to the script from your Google Account and it would stop working.

> Go to your Google Account Settings and under Security, click the Apps
>   and Websites link that will show you are list of scripts that have
>   access to your Gmail, Google Drive and other Google Services. Revoke
>   access to the one that is sending these notifications.

http://ctrlq.org/help/424-permanently-stop-google-scripts